# Vector transformation

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, c++17, stdvector

I have to copy the values of a 2D `vector` to another 2D `vector` only if the values are within some limits.

For that, I wrote.

```
[[nodiscard]] std::vector<std::vector<double>>
GetDataAfterApplyingLimits(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& input)
{
    std::vector output(
                 input.size(), std::vector<double>(input[0].size(), MISSINGVALUE));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < input[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (input[i][j] >= min_value && input[i][j] <= max_value)
                output[i][j] = input[i][j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

I am using `input[0].size()` to initialize the column size of the output `vector` above. The column dimension is not fixed.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `resize()` function of vector to change number of columns.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the column size of the output vector dynamically, you can use the max_element algorithm from the  header to find the maximum size of the inner vectors in the input vector. Here's an updated implementation of your GetDataAfterApplyingLimits function that does this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

[[nodiscard]] std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetDataAfterApplyingLimits(
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& input, double min_value, double max_value, double MISSINGVALUE)
{
    size_t max_cols = 0;
    for (const auto& inner : input) {
        max_cols = std::max(max_cols, inner.size());
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> output(input.size(), std::vector<double>(max_cols, MISSINGVALUE));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < input[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (input[i][j] >= min_value && input[i][j] <= max_value)
                output[i][j] = input[i][j];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If elements(vectors) of the input have different sizes...

```cpp
using JuggedVec = std::vector< std::vector<double> >;

[[nodiscard]]
JuggedVec GetDataAfterApplyingLimits( const JuggedVec &input )
{
    //* I don't know how these are defined...
    const double MISSINGVALUE = -99;
    const double min_value = 10;
    const double max_value = 100;

    //
    JuggedVec output;
    output.reserve( input.size() );

    for( const auto &In : input )
    {
        output.emplace_back( In.size(), MISSINGVALUE );
        auto iOut = output.back().begin();
        for( double val : In )
        {
            if( min_value<=val  &&  val<=max_value ){   *iOut=val;  }
            ++iOut;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```